# Passing Data between Mobile / Web Apps

Tags: single-sign-on

We have a third party mobile app that will link to a dashboard in our web app. The user id needs to be passed from the mobile app to the web app in this interaction so that we can retrieve the user's data in the web app. The user is logged in in the mobile app and we need to sign them into the web dashboard without prompting again for credentials. I'm considering using Encrypt-Then-Mac approach to pass the user id on the url as a query parameter OR a pseudo SSO approach where the mobile app retrieves a one time token by calling a background API and passes that along with the user id to the web app.

Can you comment on the pros/cons of these approaches or suggest a better one?

Answer (score 3):

Authenticating to the API and then receiving a token is a far better approach. This ensures that the user is authenticated and the token is the representation of that authentication. You can use a framework like [JWT](https://jwt.io/) to make such tokens.

Encrypting the User-ID is not a good idea. What this "authenticates" is that the request comes from the mobile App, which an attacker can reverse engineer to gain access to the keys. An attacker can then freely create "authentication tokens" for arbitrary user IDs.

In general, [OAuth 2](https://oauth.net/2/) may be a worthwhile thing to look into.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the token in as a part of the URL, it can be easily intercepted. The good thing is that you are keeping the token as "single use" that will prevent replay attacks. However, think about the scenario when the token is intercepted, but attacker prevents the use of the token, and uses it themselves? You should use a time-bound token to prevent such scenario. Consider using short lived JSON Web Tokens.

As an alternative, I suggest to use [OpenID Connect](https://Openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) for achieving single sign on. Host the authorization provider in the along with your web app. Both the mobile app and the web app use the same authorization provider. The flow would looks something like below:

1. User opens Mobile App, which redirects (read opens browser) to your authorization provider
2. User logs in to your authorization provider to start a session and the authorization provider redirects you back to the Mobile App with an authorization code.
3. Mobile App exchanges authorization code with Tokens (Access, Refresh, ID) from the authorization provider.
4. The access token is used to invoke backend APIs (which validate the access token).
5. Mobile App invokes WebApp dashboard
6. Since user is not logged in, Web App dashboard redirects the the user to the same authorization provider.
7. **Since user is already logged in to an authorization provider, they get redirected back to the Web App with an authorization code.**
8. Web App exchanges authorization code with Tokens (access, refresh, ID) from the authorization provider - SAME AS STEP 3
9. The access token is used to invoke the backend APIs (which validate the access token) - SAME AS STEP 4